# Google Apps Marketplace - SSO for Google App Engine Java application

Tags: google-app-engine, openid, single-sign-on, google-apps-marketplace

I don't directly get logged into my app when my navLink in "More" section of Google's universal navigation bar in a Google Apps account is clicked, instead the login page of my application is shown.

My apps marketplace manifest:

```
<ApplicationManifest xmlns="http://schemas.google.com/ApplicationManifest/2009">
  <Name>App Name</Name>
  <Description>App Description</Description>

  <!-- Administrators and users will be sent to this URL for application support -->
  <Support>
    <Link rel="support" href="http://myappid.appspot.com/help.html" />
  </Support>

  <!-- Show this link in Google's universal navigation for all users -->
  <Extension id="navLink" type="link">
    <Name>Myapp Navlink Name</Name>
    <Url>http://myappid.appspot.com/ms.jsp?hd=${DOMAIN_NAME}</Url>
  </Extension>

  <!-- Declare our OpenID realm so our app is white listed -->
  <Extension id="realm" type="openIdRealm">
    <Url>http://myappid.appspot.com/</Url>
  </Extension>

</ApplicationManifest>
```

My web.xml relevant part:

```
 <servlet>
     <servlet-name>loginJsp</servlet-name>
     <jsp-file>/login.jsp</jsp-file>
 </servlet>

 <servlet-mapping>
     <servlet-name>loginJsp</servlet-name>
     <url-pattern>/_ah/login_required</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>

 <security-constraint>
  <web-resource-collection>
   <web-resource-name>ms</web-resource-name>
   <url-pattern>/ms.jsp</url-pattern>
  </web-resource-collection>
  <auth-constraint>
   <role-name>*</role-name>
  </auth-constraint>
 </security-constraint>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a servlet to handle `http://myappid.appspot.com/ms.jsp?hd=${DOMAIN_NAME}`. It will get the domain name and redirect to a login url using the domain as `federatedIdentity`. See :

http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/users/UserService.html#createLoginURL%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.util.Set%29

With the proper `federatedIdentity` set, the user will login automatically from Google Apps.

Answer (score 0):

Also. You should add this to your application-manifest.xml:

```
<Edition id="free">
    <Name>Myapp Navlink Name</Name>
    <Extension ref="navLink" />
    <Extension ref="realm" />
</Edition>
```